# in i3wm how can I set the default layout for all works spaces

Tags: linux, default-settings, layout, i3-window-manager

By default when you start i3wm all work spaces start as vertical/horizontal split `splith/splitv` layout.

Is there a way to set the a different default like `stacking` or `tabbed` as the default for all containers on all work spaces. Some thing I can added to my `~/.i3/config`

In stead of manually specifying each work space to use a specific layout using the `mod+"w|e|s"`

https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_changing_the_container_layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default layout for new containers like this:

```
workspace_layout <default|stacking|tabbed>
```

It is all in the User's guide:
http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_layout_mode_for_new_containers